# How to bash exit from case after idle timeout

Tags: bash

We have the following bash script with `case`.

```
select opt in report1  report2 report3 ALL_reports exit
do
    case $opt in
        visit_count)
           echo "report1"
           echo "report1 done after some operation"

            echo "[2] report2"  
            echo "[3] report3" 
            echo "[4] ALL_reports" 
            echo "[5] exit"

            ;;
        report2)
           echo "report2"
           echo "report2 done after some operation"

            echo "[1] report1"  
            echo "[3] report3" 
            echo "[4] ALL_reports" 
            echo "[5] exit"


            ;;
        report3)
            echo "report3"
            echo "report3 done after some operation"

            echo "[1] report1"  
            echo "[2] report2" 
            echo "[4] ALL_reports" 
            echo "[5] exit"



            ;;
        ALL_reports)

            echo "[5] exit"
            echo "you chose choice $REPLY which is $opt"

            ;;
        exit)
            break
            ;;
        *) echo "invalid option $REPLY";;
    esac
done
```

It works fine but when the user keeps the terminal idle for some time I want to quit the shell script.

Answer (score 1):

Set TMOUT. From the man page:

```
 TMOUT  If set to a value greater than zero, TMOUT is treated as the default timeout for  the  read  builtin.
              The  select command terminates if input does not arrive after TMOUT seconds when input is coming from
              a terminal.  In an interactive shell, the value is interpreted as the number of seconds to  wait  for
              input  after issuing the primary prompt.  Bash terminates after waiting for that number of seconds if
              input does not arrive.
```

Answer (score -1):

As @William Pursell suggested use TMOUT in this way:-

```
select opt in report1  report2 report3 ALL_reports exit
do
    case $opt in
        report1)
           echo "report1"
           echo "report1 done after some operation"

            echo "[2] report2"  
            echo "[3] report3" 
            echo "[4] ALL_reports" 
            echo "[5] exit"
            TMOUT=3

            ;;
        report2)
           echo "report2"
           echo "report2 done after some operation"

            echo "[1] report1"  
            echo "[3] report3" 
            echo "[4] ALL_reports" 
            echo "[5] exit"

            TMOUT=3
            ;;
        report3)
            echo "report3"
            echo "report3 done after some operation"

            echo "[1] report1"  
            echo "[2] report2" 
            echo "[4] ALL_reports" 
            echo "[5] exit"

            TMOUT=3

            ;;
        ALL_reports)

            echo "[5] exit"
            echo "you chose choice $REPLY which is $opt"
            TMOUT=3
            ;;
        exit)
            break
            ;;
        *) echo "invalid option $REPLY";;
    esac
done
```

What this will do is terminate your script after 3 seconds after a user has submitted his option and does not select another option in the meanwhile.